# No se envía el Email de Bienvenida

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

los usuarios al registrarse deben recibir un email de Bienvenida, no se cual es el error pero no sucede.

```
    protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        't_matricula' => $data['t_matricula'],
        'numero' => rand(100, 9200),
        'matricula' => $data['matricula'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new WelcomeMail($user));
    
  
}
```

Hice un testeo con mailtrap y si envía pero de otra forma manual,

```
  $user = Auth::User();
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new WelcomeMail($user));
```

El problema solo esta en el registro, que podría ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer, es enviar el email antes de crear el usuario, ya que lo estás devolviendo, por lo que tendrás que ponerlo antes del `return`, o también podrías quitar el return, crear el usuario, y devolverlo mas tarde:

protected function create(array $data)
{

```
 $usuario = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    't_matricula' => $data['t_matricula'],
    'numero' => rand(100, 9200),
    'matricula' => $data['matricula'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
]);

Mail::to($usuario ->email)->send(new WelcomeMail($usuario));

return $usuario;

}
```

Imagino que ya tendrás la configuración del email, y la clase y todo lo demás credo, ya que sino no enviará nada.

Comment: Hola @porloscerrosΨ tienes razón con que la primera parte no tiene mucho sentido, ya que a lo mejor no crea el usuario, pero ya le ha mandado el correo. Lo del voto negativo, en caso de ser del que ha realizado la pregunta, estaría bien algún comentario diciendo que le ha pasado o si no le ha funcionado. En cuanto a lo de `$user` o he puesto porque pensaba que tendría una variable ya definida con ese nombre, ya que lo estaba usando así. He editado mi respuesta, a ver que te parece. Gracias por tu aporte

Comment: No fui yo el del voto negativo, acabo de aplicar tu solución y funciono bien

Comment: Me alegro entonces :)